# Trying to Dual Boot Kubuntu and Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

I have been trying to dual boot Windows 10 with Kubuntu 18.04. During installation, I get a partman exit code 141. I have tried several things from this site to fix it. I made sure I was using GPT. I have tried formatting in FAT32 and NTFS. I made the Linux partition ext4. Nothing works. It would be nice to get it going. But, if that is not possible, my preference would be to wipe Windows 10 completely and just run Kubuntu, since I need Linux but not Windows. Maybe I'll try to install Windows as a dual boot later. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First you install window 10 in primary partition after that one drive separate for Linux this is secondary drive, if you follow these rules and system only NTFS otherwise generating error.

Answer (score 0):

Completely format your hdd. Partition it using windows installation disk , and Install the desired windows version.
After successfully booting to windows , create a bootable media for desired distro of linux and then live boot to that.
Then install it from within the live environment.
After this the default bootloader will be grub , and you can boot to any os then.

Comment: I don't have a disk drive, only USB. It's a brand new laptop that didn't come with  a Windows disk or USB drive. I messed around with it a little more, but now it just boots to grub when I try to boot from the USB.

Comment: Go to cyber cafe and use a windows pc to Download windows 10 version only from microsoft's official website. Then burn the downloaded image to usb using "Rufus" utility. Select the correct option from uefi or bios (in rufus while burning image to disk) . After that plug in your usb in your system and boot using usb(check the bios or uefi settings so that you boot to usb). Install windows on your system then, without entering a windows key . Then successfully boot to windows and proceed for any linux distro.